# Spring Security with path variable parameters

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to create security rules based on custom url parameters (path variables).
In example. Let say I want to have user that has admin access for resources called Brand1 and Brand2 but has no access to resource called Brand3. We may edit resources using following links.

```
http://myapp/brand/edit/1
http://myapp/brand/edit/2
http://myapp/brand/edit/3
```

now in security context I would like to do something like that

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/brand/edit/{brandId}" 
           access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN') or
                   @authorizationService.hasBrandPermission(
                   #brandId, principal.username)"/>
```

The only thing I get is username. BrandId is always null.
I used to do that with @PreAuthorize and it worked but now I would like to centralized security configuration in single xml file instead of spreading it across all controller classes. Moreover when I was using @PreAuthorize my access-denied-handler did not redirect me into denied page but display ugly AccessDeniedException insead.

I would really aprecieate any ideas.

Comment: I don't get the problem. Is it that the BrandId is always null? Or is it that it does not secure the resource? Or is it the ugly AccessDeniedException page?

Answer (score 2):

Change the Spring Security version in your `pom.xml` to `4.1.0.RELEASE`:

```
<spring-security.version>4.1.0.RELEASE</spring-security.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

You may need to clean your maven project after that.

*(I know, it's an old question. Nonetheless, I faced same issue 3 years later).*

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Answer (score 1):

you can try using regular expression.

you will need to add the attribute **path-type="regex"** in your http element or **request-matcher="regex"** if your using spring security 3.1

see the documentation for more details

Comment: I though that regexp is only for defining url patterns not for referencing path variable. i.e. I may do something like that "/path/to/*.html" so it apply all URLs that match the pattern but what Im interested in is "/path/to/resource/{resourceId}" and get resourceId value in 'access' section so i.e. access="@myService.mySecurityMethod(#resourceId)"